# Want to have django-two-factor-auth skip token step if user/device logged in during the last 30 days

Tags: django, two-factor-authentication

First, if anyone has done this, please advise :)

Right now, I am thinking of subclassing **LoginView** method *get_context_data()* (from the [django-two-factor-auth](https://github.com/Bouke/django-two-factor-auth) package).

the 1st line of the new method would be:

```
if  self.steps.current == 'token':
    (pseudo code)
    if user_agent == current user_agent and last_activity < 30 days ago (from table user_sessions_session):
       return context # skip the token step
```

I see this is a [desired feature](https://github.com/Bouke/django-two-factor-auth/issues/56) but not yet implemented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forked the repository with changes [here](https://github.com/compsult/django-two-factor-auth/tree/trusted_puter) and put in a [pull request](https://github.com/Bouke/django-two-factor-auth/pull/263). You can review the changes [here](https://github.com/Bouke/django-two-factor-auth/pull/263/files) (the coverage for the changes is 100%).

Basically, if there was valid login (with a token), it sets a signed cookie limited to the login page. Logins after that will check for that signed cookie, and if it exists and has not expired, it will allow login without a token. This is the key logic:

```
def token_required(self, request):
    """
    if this user logged with a token in the last {{TWO_FACTOR_TRUSTED_DAYS}}
    days, they can skip the token steps.
    """
    end_valid_login = None
    if not request.COOKIES.get('evl'):
        return True
    try:
        end_valid_login = request.get_signed_cookie('evl',
                salt=settings.TWO_FACTOR_SALT)
    except (BadSignature, SignatureExpired) as e:
        return True
    end_valid_login_dt = datetime.strptime(end_valid_login, '%Y-%m-%d')
    if datetime.today() < end_valid_login_dt:
        #--- the cookie is valid and still within {{TWO_FACTOR_TRUSTED_DAYS}} ---#
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

***NOTE: (edit Mar 2020)***

Actually, I would recommend that anyone implementing 2FA use [Webauthn](https://webauthn.guide/). I think it makes all other methods obsolete and will become the standard everywhere. [Here is an explanation of the inherent weaknesses of other 2FA methods](https://blog.trailofbits.com/2019/06/20/getting-2fa-right-in-2019/)